# Yii2: Kartik Gridview export config?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I am using Kartik Gridview. Export is also working fine, but summary data is not getting exported, but showing fine in the view.
As also I want to change the filename of the downloaded file.

I have tried this code, but nothing seems to be working

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,        
        'showPageSummary' => true,

        'exportConfig'=> [
            GridView::EXCEL=>[
        'filename' => Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Appointments'),
        'showPageSummary' => true,
                ]
            ],
.....
```

That is I have added the `export config` in the `gridview widget` but it doesn't seems to be working.

What I am doing wrong here?
please suggest any changes.

Comment: this can help you-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697593/how-to-change-export-sheet-doc-properties-in-yii2-krajee-grid-export/45998247#45998247

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?= ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'columnSelectorOptions'=>[
                'label' => 'Columns',
                'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
            ],
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            'dropdownOptions' => [
                'label' => 'Export All',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            ]
            'exportConfig' => [
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => false,
    ],
        ]); ?>
```