# How to change export sheet/doc properties in Yii2 krajee grid export?

Tags: excel, datagridview, yii2

We have used yii2 krajee export for exporting grid data.
How can we modify default title, description , lastmodifiedby?

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_SELF,
    'exportConfig' => [
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => false,
    ],
    'filename' => 'export-list_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s'),        
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :
Here is a example of CSV. You can do like wise for others also.

```
 use yii\helpers\Html;
    use kartik\grid\GridView;
    use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

    $gridColumns = [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',
            'name',
            'desc',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ];

        // Renders a export dropdown menu
        echo ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns
        ]);

        GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'exportConfig'=> [
                GridView::CSV=>[
                    'label' => 'CSV',
                    'icon' => '',
                    'iconOptions' => '',
                    'showHeader' => false,
                    'showPageSummary' => false,
                    'showFooter' => false,
                    'showCaption' => false,
                    'filename' => 'yii',
                    'alertMsg' => 'created',
                    'options' => ['title' => 'Semicolon -  Separated Values'],
                    'mime' => 'application/csv',
                    'config' => [
                        'colDelimiter' => ";",
                        'rowDelimiter' => "\r\n",
                    ], 
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Hey @vijay bhai, Can you please help me in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229692/more-than-1-sheets-in-excel-yii2 ?

Answer (score 2):

What I did to get my task done-
I have in my header as-

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
```

Then in gridView -

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'pjax'=>true,
            'id' => 'grid',
            'toolbar' => [
                ['content'=>
                   Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>', ['ctrl-action'], ['data-pjax'=>false, 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'title'=>'Reset Grid'])
                ],
                '{export}',
                '{toggleData}'
              ],
              'panel' => [
                      'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i> Output Daily Data </h3>',
                      'type'=>'primary',
                      'before'=>Html::a(''),
                      'after'=>Html::a(''),
                      'showFooter'=>false
                   ],
              'columns' => [
                 ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

                 'id',
                 'name'
                 ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
             ],

           'responsive'=>true,
             'hover'=>true,
             'exportConfig' => [
                   GridView::CSV => ['label' => 'Export as CSV', 'filename' => 'File_Name-'.date('d-M-Y')],
                   GridView::HTML => ['label' => 'Export as HTML', 'filename' => 'File_Name -'.date('d-M-Y')],
                   GridView::PDF => ['label' => 'Export as PDF', 'filename' => 'File_Name -'.date('d-M-Y')],
                   GridView::EXCEL=> ['label' => 'Export as EXCEL', 'filename' => 'File_Name -'.date('d-M-Y')],
                   GridView::TEXT=> ['label' => 'Export as TEXT', 'filename' => 'File_Name -'.date('d-M-Y')],
                ],
                'export' => [
                   'fontAwesome' => true
                ],  
           ]); ?>
```

That worked for me.
just make changes in `'exportConfig'` section for rename file.